# JNLP - How can i deploy my application which runs and create a desktop icon for launching the a.jar?

Tags: java, installation, jnlp, java-web-start, package-managers

How can i fix this error? I have my deploy dist with all jar files included in my webserver. But once i press icon.jnlp it says that error.

icon.jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://localhost:007/dist" href="icon.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
  <information>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <vendor>Sample</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>Sample</description>
    <description kind="short">Sample</description>

    <icon href="load.png" kind="splash"/>
    <icon href="logo.png" kind="default"/>

    <shortcut online="false">
      <desktop/>
        <menu submenu="Sample">
          <menu submenu="Sample Managing System"/>
        </menu>
    </shortcut>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>

  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>

  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="http://localhost:007/dist/a.jar" main="true"/>
  </resources>

  <application-desc main-class="main.main">
  </application-desc>

</jnlp>
```

[image]

**Follow up:**

1) Download JAR Maker (works in Linux, Windows)

[image]

- Sing **all** third party jars
- your deploy jars
- Output directory: /var/tmp/project/dist
- go to JAR Signer tab

  - input jar file: a.jar

    - jarsigner location: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/bin/jarsigner
    - keystore file
    - if no key was created > click generate keystore
                            - keytool location: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/bin/keytool
                            - output keystore file: /var/tmp/keystore
                            - keystore alias: rememberthisname
                            - public key: 123456
                            - private key: 123456
                            - validity days: 0 means 6 month
                            - keystore identities
                              - valid info...
                            - press generate keystore 
                              - it will create /var/tmp/keystore and java.key.public and java.key
  - keystore authentication

    - keystore alias: rememberthisname
    - public key: 123456
    - private key: 123456
  - click sign JAR! > will tell if failed or success

Repeat this process for all other JAR files to sign!!

2) Deploy to the landing space

3) Make sure you have all  your third party is referenced

Before:

```
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="http://localhost:007/dist/a.jar" main="true"/>
  </resources>
```

After:

```
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="a.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="lib/b.jar" main="flas"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="lib/c.jar" main="flas"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="lib/d.jar" main="flas"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="lib/e.jar" main="flas"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="lib/f.jar" main="flas"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="lib/g.jar" main="flas"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="lib/h.jar" main="flas"/>
    <jar eager="true" href="lib/i.jar" main="flas"/>
  </resources>
```

Comment: That screen-shot is of no use I can see.  Click the details button, and it will pop a dialog with tabs in it.  Copy/paste the *text* from each tab as an edit to your question.  Also, be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Great tool :) I found the problem i changed the path and solved then i found unsigned problem which solved. But my application was using external other jar files. They are not now working. Myjar.jar is working with your tips. But Myjar.jar is using other wrappers like Others1.jar Others2.jar there funtionality is not working when i launch Myjar.jar.

Comment: Do i have to sign now all my other third party jars also? If it getting launched via JNLP?

Comment: Umm.. I'm pretty sure JaNeLA should warn about `main="flas"`  That attribute defaults to false, so I generally put one `main="true"` attribute and leave the rest out entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

> Do i have to sign now all my other third party jars also?

It depends how they are deployed.  If they are in extensions, the extension can have a different security level.  If the security level is sand-boxed, the Jars do no need to be signed.

But then you might face 'mixing signed & unsigned resources' warnings.  I'm not sure if it applies between extensions.  There are ways around those warnings, but I think it is simpler to deploy all Jars signed, irrespective of the security level of the extension they are used in.

Comment: First i did all jars deploy local system, but failed. Then i signed all jars and deploy to the local system, still failed. Now i am not sure how to resolve it. Myjar.jar is launched nicely. But third party jars are not getting loaded.

Comment: <jar eager="true" href="Myjar.jar" main="true"/>
<jar eager="true" href="Do i have to add also other jars here? as a long list?.jar" main="true"/>

Comment: For simplicity, list all Jars in the JNLP.  Note that by 'extension' I meant other JNLP files that are referred to from your main JNLP.  But let's keep it simple for the moment & list every Jar in the main JNLP in a single line `jar` element.  Only one jar should be marked as `main="true"`  Go through of the links on the [JWS info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), they provide great detail about what the JNLP file means, and how it all works.